# Ubuntu 20.04 cannot resume from suspension

Tags: suspend, 20.04, amd-ryzen

The Problem:

Since I upgraded my hardware, I have been having problems with resuming from suspension. The problem is that the PC will not resume from suspension. Everything boots up and works fine, the system suspends fine, but when I try to resume I get a very clearly broken login screen where half the elements are not properly loaded. The mouse cursor works but cannot click on anything, and the password prompt says "authentication failed" even though I haven't typed in a password or even touched my keyboard at all. After like 10 seconds of that, the login screen disappears and the computer starts rapid firing [these error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Of403.jpg). Excuse the photo, I would have copy&pasted the errors from the logs if I could find them. I `grep`d entire `/var/log` using a whole bunch of keywords, they're not there. Nothing works except hitting the reset button on the PC case. After a restart the computer boots up fine, but as I said, in the system logs there is no trace of what happened.

My system:

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04 with kernel version 5.4.0. I also tried Manjaro, basically the same thing except without the barrage of error messages, which also don't get logged.
- DE: GNOME v3.36 on both Ubuntu and Manjaro
- CPU: AMD Ryzen 3600
- GPU: Nvidia GTX 970, driver 440 on all distros
- Mobo: MSI b450 gaming plus max

What I have tried so far:

- BIOS is updated to the latest version I can find on MSI's website.
- Upgraded to Ubuntu kernel 5.4.3.
- All drives report clean smartctl self-tests.
- Swap partition is larger than installed memory.
- In `/etc/default/grub`, the correct UUID is set for `resume=`. I also added `modprobe.blacklist=amdgpu` in the same file.
- Tried multiple distros (Ubuntu, Pop!_OS[which is essentially ubuntu, I know], Manjaro), they all fail to resume.
- Did a complete wipe and reinstall of graphics drivers.
- Tried resuming without any USB devices (besides kb&m).
- Muttered obscenities under my breath.

Notes:

- I dual boot with Windows 10, installed on a separate drive. It has no problem waking up from sleep.
- Live Linux environments also seem to have no problems resuming from suspension. Only when booting off a proper installation do I have this issue.
- My mouse lags like hell and/or stutters seemingly at random. On any OS, including Windows. Everything works perfectly on Windows, except this mouse thing. This is the only global problem that is shared between Linux and OS, so it could help crack the case maybe.

As I said, I have been having these problems since I upgraded my CPU/mobo/RAM a few days ago. Before that everything worked perfectly. I'm worried there might be something wrong with my new hardware.

Anyway, thanks in advance

Comment: I will bet 1000 dogecoin the problem goes away if you run nouveau drivers not nvidia ... not a solution if you must use nvidia ... YMMV

Answer (score 3):

Think I found a workaround, at least for my hardware. Have a completely different setup but experienced exactly the described behaviour two times within weeks, the last time three days ago. During the last ten days, after I had made changes to the BIOS setup, Resume from Suspend would never work and always showed a black screen with (today) the symbols ^@ on the top left. Only way out: Pressing the power button for five seconds, leading to a hard shutdown.
My workaround: In BIOS setup I found the setting which obviously didn't work together with the Resume routine: In my HP EliteBook 850G6, in Port Options, the setting 'Thunderbolt Type C Ports' must remain 'on' (which is the factory default) and must not be turned off. Now Resume works fine, again.
But I cannot state whether the behaviour initially described in this thread will never appear again.
Hope that helps at least someone (experiencing only dead Resumes), if not the originator of this thread.

Answer (score 1):

I have an Acer Aspire 5 4700U.  I had this issue with 20.04.  I found out the the amdgpu driver failed to compile on pre-5.8 kernels.  So, I upgraded to 20.10 which is based on the 5.8 kernel and my suspend-resume and a few other problems went away.  I checked that I do have a functioning amdgpu kernel module now.

Good luck.

Comment: I've faced with the unsuspending issue on ubuntu 22.04 and 5.19.0-32 kernel.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**: Upgrade your kernel.

This has been a real nightmare for me. I tried everything – messing with the `.conf` file, playing around with `grub`, toggling Nvidia modes... I even gave different Nvidia drivers a shot: 525, 535, 470 – but nothing worked. I kept getting errors (no HDMI connection...) and every time I woke my system from sleep, there was just a black screen staring back at me.

But guess what fixed it? The darn kernel. I updated Ubuntu to the latest 23.04 version with 6.2 kernel, and bam, all the problems vanished into thin air. Nvidia's behaving perfectly now. I'd ticked the box for Third Party software during the Ubuntu install, so I didn't have to do diddly-squat after getting it up and running. As of today, I'm still not quite sure what it could have been. The CPU I'm using is from the 13th Intel generation, released just this year, so there might have also been some incompatibilities at play... Hopefully, this info helps out anyone else in the same boat.

This is my laptop configuration:

- CPU: Intel Core i7 13700H
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTC 1650 4GB
- SSD: 2TB Corsair Core XT
- OS: Ubuntu 23.04